# Error while runing "pod install" command in macbook catalina 10.15.4

Tags: macos, cocoapods, macos-catalina, appium-android

I have installed cocoapods which got installed and after that i ran a command **pod install** but it is giving error as -

```
[!] An error occurred while processing the pre-install hook of the Podfile.
uninitialized constant Pod::Target::BuildType

Did you mean?  Pod::BuildType
```

> /Users/joycefernandes/Downloads/WordPress-iOS-develop/Podfile:407:in `block (3 levels) in from_ruby'
>     /Users/joycefernandes/Downloads/WordPress-iOS-develop/Podfile:392:in`each'
>    /Users/joycefernandes/Downloads/WordPress-iOS-develop/Podfile:392:in `block (2 levels) in from_ruby'
>   /Users/joycefernandes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:162:in`pre_install!'
>    /Users/joycefernandes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/cocoapods>-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:829:in >`run_podfile_pre_install_hook'
>       /Users/joycefernandes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:817:in`block in run_podfile_pre_install_hooks'
>     /Users/joycefernandes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:145:in `message'
>    /Users/joycefernandes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:816:in`run_podfile_pre_install_hooks'
>    /Users/joycefernandes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:250:in `block in download_dependencies'
>    /Users/joycefernandes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in`section'
>    /Users/joycefernandes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:248:in `download_dependencies'
>    /Users/joycefernandes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:157:in`install!'
>   /Users/joycefernandes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
>       /Users/joycefernandes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in`run'
>       /Users/joycefernandes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
>       /Users/joycefernandes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/bin/pod:55:in`'
>       /Users/joycefernandes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/bin/pod:23:in `load'
>       /Users/joycefernandes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/bin/pod:23:in`'
>       /Users/joycefernandes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
>       /Users/joycefernandes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in`'

My pod version is **1.9.1** and i am using **Mac Catalina**

This is my podfile content -

```
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'

inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

platform :ios, '11.0'
workspace 'WordPress.xcworkspace'

## Pods shared between all the targets
## ===================================
##
def wordpress_shared
    ## for production:
    pod 'WordPressShared', '~> 1.8.16'

    ## for development:
    # pod 'WordPressShared', :path => '../WordPress-iOS-Shared'

    ## while PR is in review:
    # pod 'WordPressShared', :git => 'https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-iOS-Shared.git', :branch => ''
    # pod 'WordPressShared', :git => 'https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-iOS-Shared.git', :commit  => 'efe5a065f3ace331353595ef85eef502baa23497'
end

def aztec
    ## When using a tagged version, feel free to comment out the WordPress-Aztec-iOS line below.
    ## When using a commit number (during development) you should provide the same commit number for both pods.
    ##
    ## pod 'WordPress-Aztec-iOS', :git => 'https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/AztecEditor-iOS.git', :commit => 'ba8524aba1332550efb05cad583a85ed3511beb5'
    ## pod 'WordPress-Editor-iOS', :git => 'https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/AztecEditor-iOS.git', :commit => 'ba8524aba1332550efb05cad583a85ed3511beb5'
    ## pod 'WordPress-Editor-iOS', :git => 'https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/AztecEditor-iOS.git', :tag => '1.5.0.beta.1'
    ## pod 'WordPress-Editor-iOS', :path => '../AztecEditor-iOS'
    pod 'WordPress-Editor-iOS', '~> 1.19.0'
end

def wordpress_ui
    ## for production:
    pod 'WordPressUI', '~> 1.6.0'
    ## for development:
    #pod 'WordPressUI', :path => '../WordPressUI-iOS'
    ## while PR is in review:
    #pod 'WordPressUI', :git => 'https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPressUI-iOS', :branch => 'issue/downloaded-image-not-set'
    # pod 'WordPressUI', :git => 'https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPressUI-iOS', :commit => '85b2a8cfb9d3c27194a14bdcb3c8391e13fbaa0f'
    #pod 'WordPressUI', :git => 'https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPressUI-iOS', :branch => 'fancybutton-public-isprimary'
    #pod 'WordPressUI', :git => 'https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPressUI-iOS', :commit => '05d82b280a4b65e084f34e282ec392cb80afdec1'
end

def wordpress_kit
    pod 'WordPressKit', '~> 4.8.0'
    #pod 'WordPressKit', :git => 'https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPressKit-iOS.git', :tag => ''
    #pod 'WordPressKit', :git => 'https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPressKit-iOS.git', :branch => ''
    #pod 'WordPressKit', :git => 'https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPressKit-iOS.git', :commit => ''
    #pod 'WordPressKit', :path => '../WordPressKit-iOS'
end

def shared_with_all_pods
    wordpress_shared
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '3.5.2'
    pod 'FormatterKit/TimeIntervalFormatter', '1.8.2'
    pod 'NSObject-SafeExpectations', '~> 0.0.4'
end

def shared_with_networking_pods
    pod 'Alamofire', '4.8.0'
    pod 'Reachability', '3.2'

    wordpress_kit
end

def shared_test_pods
    pod 'OHHTTPStubs', '6.1.0'
    pod 'OHHTTPStubs/Swift', '6.1.0'
    pod 'OCMock', '3.4.3'
end

def shared_with_extension_pods
    pod 'Gridicons', '~> 1.0.1'
    pod 'ZIPFoundation', '~> 0.9.8'
    pod 'Down', '~> 0.6.6'
end

def gutenberg(options)
    options[:git] = 'http://github.com/wordpress-mobile/gutenberg-mobile/'
    local_gutenberg = ENV['LOCAL_GUTENBERG']
    if local_gutenberg
      options = { :path => local_gutenberg.include?('/') ? local_gutenberg : '../gutenberg-mobile' }
    end
    pod 'Gutenberg', options
    pod 'RNTAztecView', options

    gutenberg_dependencies options
end

def gutenberg_dependencies(options)
    dependencies = [
        'FBReactNativeSpec',
        'FBLazyVector',
        'React',
        'ReactCommon',
        'RCTRequired',
        'RCTTypeSafety',
        'React-Core',
        'React-CoreModules',
        'React-RCTActionSheet',
        'React-RCTAnimation',
        'React-RCTBlob',
        'React-RCTImage',
        'React-RCTLinking',
        'React-RCTNetwork',
        'React-RCTSettings',
        'React-RCTText',
        'React-RCTVibration',
        'React-cxxreact',
        'React-jsinspector',
        'React-jsi',
        'React-jsiexecutor',
        'Yoga',
        'Folly',
        'glog',
        'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view',
        'react-native-safe-area',
        'react-native-video',
        'RNSVG',
        'ReactNativeDarkMode',
        'react-native-slider',
        'react-native-linear-gradient'
    ]
    if options[:path]
        podspec_prefix = options[:path]
    else
        tag_or_commit = options[:tag] || options[:commit]
        podspec_prefix = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wordpress-mobile/gutenberg-mobile/#{tag_or_commit}"
    end

    for pod_name in dependencies do
        pod pod_name, :podspec => "#{podspec_prefix}/react-native-gutenberg-bridge/third-party-podspecs/#{pod_name}.podspec.json"
    end
end

## WordPress iOS
## =============
##
target 'WordPress' do
    project 'WordPress/WordPress.xcodeproj'

    shared_with_all_pods
    shared_with_networking_pods
    shared_with_extension_pods

    ## Gutenberg (React Native)
    ## =====================
    ##
    gutenberg :commit => '1186db17990c7ffbd325f77ff7fe96401639e1d1'

    ## Third party libraries
    ## =====================
    ##
    pod 'Charts', '~> 3.2.2'
    pod 'Gifu', '3.2.0'
    pod 'AppCenter', '2.5.1', :configurations => ['Release-Internal', 'Release-Alpha']
    pod 'AppCenter/Distribute', '2.5.1', :configurations => ['Release-Internal', 'Release-Alpha']
    pod 'MRProgress', '0.8.3'
    pod 'Starscream', '3.0.6'
    pod 'SVProgressHUD', '2.2.5'
    pod 'ZendeskSupportSDK', '5.0.0'
    pod 'AlamofireImage', '3.5.2'
    pod 'AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator', '~> 2.4'
    pod 'FSInteractiveMap', :git => 'https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/FSInteractiveMap.git', :tag => '0.2.0'
    pod 'JTAppleCalendar', '~> 8.0.2'

    ## Automattic libraries
    ## ====================
    ##

    # Production
    pod 'Automattic-Tracks-iOS', '~> 0.4.4'
    # While in PR
    # pod 'Automattic-Tracks-iOS', :git => 'https://github.com/Automattic/Automattic-Tracks-iOS.git', :branch => 'feature/Swift-5-migration'

    pod 'NSURL+IDN', '~> 0.4'

    pod 'WPMediaPicker', '~> 1.6.1'
    ## while PR is in review:
    # pod 'WPMediaPicker', :git => 'https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/MediaPicker-iOS.git', :branch => ''
    # pod 'WPMediaPicker', :path => '../MediaPicker-iOS'

    pod 'Gridicons', '~> 1.0.1'

    pod 'WordPressAuthenticator', '~> 1.16.0-beta.3'
    # While in PR
    # pod 'WordPressAuthenticator', :git => 'https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPressAuthenticator-iOS.git', :branch => ''
    # pod 'WordPressAuthenticator', :git => 'https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPressAuthenticator-iOS.git', :commit => ''
    # pod 'WordPressAuthenticator', :path => '../WordPressAuthenticator-iOS'

    pod 'MediaEditor', '~> 1.0.1'
    # pod 'MediaEditor', :git => 'https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/MediaEditor-iOS.git', :commit => 'a4178ed9b0f3622faafb41dd12503e26c5523a32'
    # pod 'MediaEditor', :path => '../MediaEditor-iOS'

    aztec
    wordpress_ui

    target 'WordPressTest' do
        inherit! :search_paths

        shared_test_pods
        pod 'Nimble', '~> 7.3.1'
    end


    post_install do
        puts 'Patching RCTShadowView to fix nested group block - it could be removed after upgrade to 0.62'
        %x(patch Pods/React-Core/React/Views/RCTShadowView.m < patches/react-native+0.61.5.patch)


        ## Convert the 3rd-party license acknowledgements markdown into html for use in the app
        require 'commonmarker'

        project_root = File.dirname(__FILE__)
        acknowledgements = 'Acknowledgments'
        markdown = File.read("#{project_root}/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-WordPress/Pods-WordPress-acknowledgements.markdown")
        rendered_html = CommonMarker.render_html(markdown, :DEFAULT)
        styled_html = "<head>
                         <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">
                         <style>
                           body {
                             font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
                             font-size: 16px;
                             color: #1a1a1a;
                             margin: 20px;
                           }
                          @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
                           body {
                            background: #1a1a1a;
                            color: white;
                           }
                          }
                           pre {
                            white-space: pre-wrap;
                           }
                         </style>
                         <title>
                           #{acknowledgements}
                         </title>
                       </head>
                       <body>
                         #{rendered_html}
                       </body>"

          ## Remove the <h1>, since we've promoted it to <title>
          styled_html = styled_html.sub("<h1>Acknowledgements</h1>", '')

          ## The glog library's license contains a URL that does not wrap in the web view,
          ## leading to a large right-hand whitespace gutter.  Work around this by explicitly
          ## inserting a <br> in the HTML.  Use gsub juuust in case another one sneaks in later.
          styled_html = styled_html.gsub('p?hl=en#dR3YEbitojA/COPYING', 'p?hl=en#dR3YEbitojA/COPYING<br>')

        File.write("#{project_root}/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-WordPress/acknowledgements.html", styled_html)
    end
end


## Share Extension
## ===============
##
target 'WordPressShareExtension' do
    project 'WordPress/WordPress.xcodeproj'

    shared_with_extension_pods

    aztec
    shared_with_all_pods
    shared_with_networking_pods
    wordpress_ui
end


## DraftAction Extension
## =====================
##
target 'WordPressDraftActionExtension' do
    project 'WordPress/WordPress.xcodeproj'

    shared_with_extension_pods

    aztec
    shared_with_all_pods
    shared_with_networking_pods
    wordpress_ui
end


## Today Widget
## ============
##
target 'WordPressTodayWidget' do
    project 'WordPress/WordPress.xcodeproj'

    shared_with_all_pods
    shared_with_networking_pods

    wordpress_ui
end

## All Time Widget
## ============
##
target 'WordPressAllTimeWidget' do
    project 'WordPress/WordPress.xcodeproj'

    shared_with_all_pods
    shared_with_networking_pods

    wordpress_ui
end

## This Week Widget
## ============
##
target 'WordPressThisWeekWidget' do
    project 'WordPress/WordPress.xcodeproj'

    shared_with_all_pods
    shared_with_networking_pods

    wordpress_ui
end

## Notification Content Extension
## ==============================
##
target 'WordPressNotificationContentExtension' do
    project 'WordPress/WordPress.xcodeproj'

    wordpress_kit
    wordpress_shared
    wordpress_ui
end



## Notification Service Extension
## ==============================
##
target 'WordPressNotificationServiceExtension' do
    project 'WordPress/WordPress.xcodeproj'

    wordpress_kit
    wordpress_shared
    wordpress_ui
end


## Mocks
## ===================
##
def wordpress_mocks
  pod 'WordPressMocks', '~> 0.0.8'
  # pod 'WordPressMocks', :git => 'https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPressMocks.git', :commit => ''
  # pod 'WordPressMocks', :git => 'https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPressMocks.git', :branch => 'add/screenshot-mocks'
  # pod 'WordPressMocks', :path => '../WordPressMocks'
end


## Screenshot Generation
## ===================
##
target 'WordPressScreenshotGeneration' do
    project 'WordPress/WordPress.xcodeproj'

    wordpress_mocks
    pod 'SimulatorStatusMagic'
end

## UI Tests
## ===================
##
target 'WordPressUITests' do
    project 'WordPress/WordPress.xcodeproj'

    wordpress_mocks
end

# Static Frameworks:
# ============
#
# Make all pods that are not shared across multiple targets into static frameworks by overriding the static_framework? function to return true
# Linking the shared frameworks statically would lead to duplicate symbols
# A future version of CocoaPods may make this easier to do. See https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7428
shared_targets = ['WordPressFlux']
pre_install do |installer|
    static = []
    dynamic = []
    installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|

        # Statically linking Sentry results in a conflict with `NSDictionary.objectAtKeyPath`, but dynamically
        # linking it resolves this.
        if pod.name == "Sentry"
          dynamic << pod
          next
        end

        # If this pod is a dependency of one of our shared targets, it must be linked dynamically
        if pod.target_definitions.any? { |t| shared_targets.include? t.name }
          dynamic << pod
          next
        end
        static << pod
        pod.instance_variable_set(:@build_type, Pod::Target::BuildType.static_framework)
    end
    puts "Installing #{static.count} pods as static frameworks"
    puts "Installing #{dynamic.count} pods as dynamic frameworks"
end
```

Comment: FYI to format your code, either indent every line by 4 spaces or just select them all and hit `ctrl + K`/ `cmmd + K`

Comment: Can you post your podfile. It’s likely there’s an issue with it.

Comment: @WarrenBurton I have attached my podfile please varify once.

Comment: @Nitishawasthi I was able to `pod install` on Catalina + Xcode 11.4 . my `pod --version` is `1.8.4` . I did need to install an extra gem `gem install commonmarker` but other than that the install was almost clean. I suggest you ensure you are using the latest version of cocoa pods.

Comment: @WarrenBurton COCOAPODS: 1.8.4 is my cocoapods version which i got by running cat Podfile.lock command

Comment: Ok , I used a dummy project with guesses at what the targets were. It must be something to do with your project. Have you tried following the hint in the error log by modifying the pre install hook with the suggested type.